# Group Examples: Best and Worst case of subgroup conjugate intersection

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

What would be two (M = maximal subgroup,G = nonabelian group) pairs for the smallest possible and largest possible intersection of the subgroup with its conjugates? The smallest intersection is 1 the identity only, and the largest intersection is such that the number of nonidentity elements contained in all conjugates of $M$ is $(|M|-1)|M:G|$.

Comment: I don't know what $M$ and $G$ are, but in an abelian group the only conjugate of a subgroup is itself, so the size of the intersection is the size of the subgroup.

Comment: thank you! improved my question based on your comment.

Comment: If $|M:G|$ is the index of $M$ in $G$, then it's at least two, so $(|M|-1)|M:G|$ is at least $2(|M|-1)$, which is bigger than $|M|$. How can an intersection be bigger than the things that are doing the intersecting?

Comment: This was a theorem about the number of nonidentity elements contained in all conjugates and I wanted an example to max out the bound. I badly misstated that, think it is fixed now thanks to you.

Comment: The smallest occurs in $S_3$.

Comment: If $G$ is the dihedral group of order $2p$, with $p$ prime, and $M$ is a subgroup of order $2$, then all $p$ of the elements of order $2$ are conjugate, which equals $(|M|-1)|M:G|$. But the intersection of the subgroup with its conjugates is just the identity.

Comment: So, where do we stand now, rain?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The example was useful but I still lack a good understanding of the intersections of conjugates of subgroups. I may try to use GAP to search for examples with large intersection

Comment: OK. Maybe you'll report back here on what you find.